# Getting incorrect day for the given time format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have a time given like so..
`var utcTime = "\(dic["Due_Date"]!)"`

Here the `utcTime` displays `"2020-08-23T18:49:15"`

I’m splitting it into different components like so..

```
self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
self.dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
self.dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") 
   
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:utcTime) {
    let monthInt = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date) //Displays 8
    let dayInt = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date) //Displays 24 instead of 23
    let yearInt = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date) //Displays 2020
}
```

Here I’m getting all the components proper except the day. While the `utcTime` displays `"2020-08-23T18:49:15"`, the day instead of displaying 23 displays 24. The day is given by `dayInt` above.

Comment: I'm getting `utcTime` from the API. Is there any way I can show the time zone of `utcTime` itself...?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a different date because of using `Calendar.current` to get the date components of a date in a different time zone. If you want to get the date components in a specific timezone, create a calendar instance and specify the timezone.

```
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:utcTime) {
    var calendar  = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
    
    let monthInt = calendar.component(.month, from: date) //Displays 8
    let dayInt = calendar.component(.day, from: date) //Displays 23
    let yearInt = calendar.component(.year, from: date) //Displays 2020
}
```

Comment: its not working @Jithin..its giving the month as december

Comment: What is the date string for which you are getting month as December?